# Prevent web brower cache file from being downloaded

Tags: security, caching, web, browser

My website has some of its files temporarly saved in the web browser cache.
Concerning CSS and images files, no problem but for some files it's a real security issue.

Is there a way to prevent some files from :
- being downloaded from the cache ?
- being visible in the cache ?

or crypt them maybe

Thanks.

David

Answer (score 0):

Well you can configure your webserver so it sends certain http headers for certain file types such as javascript. For example for Apache web server we can use [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) module.

Another option is to add a random string to the end of each file that should not be cached by the web browser. for example the file script_name.js can be server as script_name.js?somerandomstring